# How to use UDFs in NiFi?

Tags: hive, user-defined-functions, apache-nifi

I'm trying to encrypt data such that only some columns are encrypted.
Example: {col1, col2, col3, col4} => {col1, encrypted(col2), col3, encrypted(col4)}

If my encryption process could be done with the use of a udf, how could I register and/or use the udf in NiFi?

In Hive, this could be done by first registering the udf such as:
create temporary function udf_name as 'abc.efg.udf_class_name' using jar 'hdfs/path/to/jar/abc.jar';
And then executing: select col1, udf_name(col2), col3, udf_name(col4) from table;

In NiFi, there is the QueryRecord which allows me to execute a select query on the content of the flowfile. However, I'm not sure how to register the udf in NiFi.

On similar point, is it possible to execute multiple sql commands in NiFi on the same flowfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDFs are not supported in Apache NiFi, as far as I know. However, if your source data comes under the type of data the NiFi Record Reader/Writer APIs support i.e. CSV, Avro, JSON, etc., you can use `ConvertRecord` processor.

- Configure `ConvertRecord` processor with the `Record Reader` set to the source data type, for example `CSVReader` and set `Record Writer` to `ScriptedRecordSetWriter`.
- ScriptedRecordSetWriter has to be then configured with the scripting language of your choice: Clojure & Groovy would work in your case, I guess.
- Then  provide the script to do the encryption in either the `Script File` or `Script Body` field.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is an open Jira [NIFI-4132](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4132) to implement this logic natively, but it is not in scope for an upcoming release at this time.